# How to rotate landscape only with Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

This is my last step of the app, everything else is done.

I'm using cocos2d, and no matter what I do, I cannot get the app to rotate. It HAS to only rotate landscape with the way my app is set up.

Here's my GameConfig.h

```
#ifndef __GAME_CONFIG_H
#define __GAME_CONFIG_H

//
// Supported Autorotations:
//      None,
//      UIViewController,
//      CCDirector
//
#define kGameAutorotationNone 0
#define kGameAutorotationCCDirector 1
#define kGameAutorotationUIViewController 2

//
// Define here the type of autorotation that you want for your game
//
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationUIViewController

#endif // __GAME_CONFIG_H
```

And my AppDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method,

```
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    //[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
#else
   // [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
#endif
```

And RootController

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );
    }

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    //
    // Assuming that the main window has the size of the screen
    // BUG: This won't work if the EAGLView is not fullscreen
    ///
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;


    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)      
        rect = screenRect;

    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        rect.size = CGSizeMake( screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width );

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    EAGLView *glView = [director openGLView];
    float contentScaleFactor = [director contentScaleFactor];

    if( contentScaleFactor != 1 ) {
        rect.size.width *= contentScaleFactor;
        rect.size.height *= contentScaleFactor;
    }
    glView.frame = rect;
}
```

In the Info.plist I have both landscape orientations in the supported list.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

to your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method

Comment: really strange. make sure that you place this code to the applicationDidFinishLaunching method, then place the breakpoint, make sure that it was called, than place breakpoint to the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Comment: The shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in RootController is NOT being called it appears, what could cause that?

Comment: Upon further inspection, it appears NONE of the method in RootViewController are being called. I don't understand how that's possible, when in finishLoading contains this line, `viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`